# Sql to Criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

Following query is working with sql:

```
SELECT
    aa.activity_id, a.title
FROM
    activity as a, activity_attendee as aa, activity_attendee as ab
WHERE
    aa.attendee_id = 50
    and
    a.id = aa.activity_id
    and
    ab.attendee_id = 1              
    and
    a.id = ab.activity_id
```

which should/gives back all activities where both attendees are set (AND).

I thave tried it following criteria:

```
        .createAlias("activityAttendee", "attendee")
        .add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.conjunction()
        .add(Restrictions.in("attendee.pk.attendee.id", values))));
```

which gives back an empty list and not what I get with bare SQL.

For this obviously I have following tables "ACTIVITY", "ACTIVITY_ATTENDEE" and "ATTENDEE". All is used as Many-to-many but table "ACTIVITY_ATTENDEE" has some extra columns in join table. All is working with criteria when only used one attendee, but not with many.

Comment: First of all your SQL Query use old comma syntax, you should use `JOIN` syntax

Comment: Ok, thanks. Although its not relevant for the question. The hibernate-criteria is not working.. SQL is working as expected.

Comment: That's why I used comment. Good practice is vital ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 .createAlias("activityAttendee", "aa")
        .add(Restrictions.in("aa.pk.attendee.id", values))
 .createAlias("activityAttendee", "ab")
        .add(Restrictions.in("ab.pk.attendee.id", values));
```

As you have it in SQL:

```
 .createAlias("activityAttendee", "aa")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("aa.pk.attendee.id", 50))
 .createAlias("activityAttendee", "ab")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("ab.pk.attendee.id", 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately it throws following exception:

org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: activityAttendee

Comment: Did you notice the two different alias names "aa" and "ab" in createAlias?

Comment: There is a bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-879 and https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7882. They  don't seem to solve it, because "criteria API is considered deprecated".

Comment: yes, i saw the different alias.
it seems to be this issue.. thanks for clarification! when criteria api is deprecated - what else should be used? As above is part of a bigger query, how can it be solved in another way?